# Vertical line on Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

May I ask as to how to create a vertical line that extends all the way down the right side of the listed items on this website? since I'll place the main content after the vertical line I'm trying to figure out

```
.first a.nav-link {
  background-color: #ebe0dd;
}

a.nav-link {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: lighter;
  
  
}
```

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light d-flex flex-md-column">
      <button
      class = "navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#sidebar"
      aria-controls="sidebar"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle Navigation">

      <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      

      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse sidebar" id = "sidebar">
        <ul class = "navbar-nav w-750 my-3 d-flex  flex-md-column text-center ">
          <li class = "first"><a href="#" class = "nav-link" aria-current = "page">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link">To Pay</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >To Ship</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >To Receive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >Completed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >Cancelled</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>

    </nav>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the **border-end** class to the **ul** element:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light flex-column" style="height: 100vh;">
      <button
      class = "navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#sidebar"
      aria-controls="sidebar"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle Navigation">

      <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      

      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse sidebar" id="sidebar">
        <ul class = "navbar-nav h-100 w-750 my-3 d-flex  flex-column text-center border-end">
          <li class = "first"><a href="#" class = "nav-link" aria-current = "page">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link">To Pay</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >To Ship</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >To Receive</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >Completed</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class = "nav-link" >Cancelled</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>

    </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend it up to 100vh? I need to have a vertical line that will extends from top to bottom of the website :(

Comment: Chris. To do that: 1. Set the navbar height to 100vh. 2. Add the **h-100** class to the ul. See the updated snippet.

Comment: That works well but I still have questions to ask, do I mind where I can contact you?

Comment: I you have further questions regarding bootstrap, please extend this question or create a new one and the whole community will try to help you.

Comment: Hi! I changed my codes, but the same problem again wherein how to apply vertical line that will act as a divider of the sidebar and the main element https://jsfiddle.net/chrismontage/43j1z0L8/ please check for more understanding hehe

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chrismontage/43j1z0L8/4/ i mean this hehe